# javascript variable shows as NaN when passed to a function

Tags: javascript

```
a=["s21aSi"]

gPf = function(a) {
    var c;
    a.forEach(function(b) {
        c = b
    })

    gPg(c);
    console.log('Inside gPf '+c)
}

gPg = function(z) {
    console.log('Inside gPg', +z)
}

gPf(a)
```

Why does `z` show as `Nan` when I do `console.log` inside `gPg`. It's a string inside `gPf` but show `Nan` when it's inside `gPg`

Comment: `, +z` <= you have a typo with the comma, so it is trying to parse the `z` because of the plus sign

Answer (score 4):

delete '+' before z:

```
gPg = function(z) {
    console.log('Inside gPg', z)
}
```

or

```
gPg = function(z) {
    console.log(`Inside gPg ${z}`)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are changing the signal of a `Not-A-Number`, when you add before a number a signal(+ or -) you a force change the signal of this number, when you add a signal before a string, the JS force a convertion in this string to number, but the string isn't a number, so JS convert this to `NaN`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) to more details.

So to your code to work, you need remove `+` before a variable `z`, like this:

```js
a = ["s21aSi"]

gPf = function(a) {
  var c;
  a.forEach(function(b) {
    c = b
  })

  gPg(c);
  console.log('Inside gPf:', c)
}

gPg = function(z) {
  console.log('Inside gPg:', z)
}

gPf(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`'Inside gPf '+c` the plus sign (+) is being used to concatenate 2 strings.

`'Inside gPg', +z` the plus sign (+) is used as a math (addition) function